# Refresh multiple elements in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the the following function to load content in a div and refresh the content in that div every 10 seconds:

```
$(function () {
var timer,
    updateContent; 
function resetTimer() {
    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = window.setTimeout(updateContent, 10000);
}
updateContent = function () {
    resetTimer();
    $.get('modules/b.php', function (data) {
        $('#main').html(data);
    });
};
updateContent();
$(document.body).on('mousemove keydown', resetTimer);
```

});

I have a contact form in the loaded content, that I, for obvious reasons, would like to exclude from the refresh. Is this possible, or is it otherwise possible to declare the divs that I would like to refresh?

Comment: You'll just need to make sure that the form is not in the #main div.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can save the values you need before the ajax call, and set them again after. 2) If this messes with the user cursor, you can use absolute positioning and not have the entry box be a descendant of #main. 3) Or the obvious way: you can restructure the call where you are not updating #main, but only what you need.

Other than that, there is not a way to magically exclude an item from the html overwrite.

Comment: I tried to exclude the form from the #main div but without success. There are basically three divs loaded. One holding the form, one with messages and one with user information. How do I need to change the function so that I update the messages and user div but not the div holding the form.

Comment: I am assuming you mean that those three divs are childs of #main. The easiest thing to do would be to change your php function to generate html for the messages and user div, instead of all of main. 

You could also save the form div, update #main html, and then apply your old form div, but I would recommend against that.